# What is the meaning of the sentence "Get a punch above your weight mug for your mother-in-law Helena"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I looked up the meaning of the phrase **punch above your weight** in  *Urban Dictionary*. The *Urban Dictionary* is not a good source to find words or phrases because there are many mistakes on that online dictionary. Anyone can give the definition of a word or a phrase!

In the end I found the following sentence:

> 1. **Get a punch above your weight mug for your mother-in-law Helena**.

A better example [from UD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=punch%20above%20your%20weight) is:

> 2. Jeff was **punching above his weight** when he was dating Liz. She's way too hot for him.

But I still don't understand the meaning of the first sentence. What does "punch above your weight mug for your mother-in-law" mean? I also don't understand the meaning of the phrase **punch above your weight** in that sentence.

**UPDATE June 2023**
I cannot create a link to that online content because every time somebody looks up the meaning of the phrase *punch above your weight* in *Urban Dictionary* they find different sentences! I've tried to find again the sentence *Get a punch above your weight mug for your mother-in-law Helena* in *Urban Dictionary* and that was impossible.

Comment: Are you sure that example doesn't say: _Get a punch above your weight mug for your [cousin_ (or _friend_) _Julia](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=punch%20above%20your%20weight)_?

Comment: That's not an author example, that's the urban dictionary trying to sell products. Whatever term you look up, they'll ask you if you want a "[term you looked up]" mug or other item that can be written upon.

Comment: Punch-above-your weight mug.

Comment: If your mother-in-law is the least bit overweight, I would strongly suggest against such a mug.

Comment: It means a mug with the words "punch above your weight" printed on it.  To "punch above your weight" is an idiom, not slang.  It means to perform or achieve results better than expected and beyond your ability.  A good way to find the meaning of idioms is to do a google search like this: **define: "to punch above one's weight"**.

Comment: By the way, Urban Dictionary is more or less useless because anybody can add anything to it. Much of the content is total nonsense. It's completely unreliable for definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused.

Firstly English Language Learners **should not use Urban Dictionary** as a main source.  There is too much there that is unfiltered, and there is too much that is just wrong.

"Punch above your weight" is an expression in boxing, it means "be able to punch as strongly as someone who weighs more than you do". Usually heavier boxers punch harder.  If you are punching above your weight, you are the equal of someone who is heavier than you are.

It can also mean to have a boxing fight with someone who is in a heavier weight class than you are.

Metaphorically this can mean to start a relationship with someone who is more attractive than you are.

Finally, this has nothing to do with mugs.  Urban Dictionary makes money by selling mugs.  You can get a mug with the expression "punch above your weight" written on it.

The link is suggesting that you (Helena) should buy a mug with the expression "Punch above your weight" written on it, as a gift for your mother-in-law.  For some reason it thinks your mother-in-law's name is Helena.... I don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

You original sentence could use some punctuation tweaks.

> Get a punch-above-your-weight mug for your mother-in-law, Helena!

or

> Get a "punch above your weight" mug for your mother-in-law, Helena!

In either case, you are probably suggesting that Helena get a mug that has the sentence "punch above your weight" inscribed on it.

In general, the meaning of "[punching above one's weight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/punch-above-your-weight)" is not limited to dating. It means that one is doing something significantly better than one might be expected to. You can use it in all sorts of cases including sporting, schooling, countries, etc.

> Despite a small population of 35 million, Canada punches above its weight when it comes to UN peacekeeping.
>
> My niece might be tiny and skinny, but she punches way above her weight once she gets on the football field.
>
> Caltech punches above its weight for a university with so few students.

In fact, I don't often see the expression used in dating context because it's usually reserved for a more feisty depiction.

Comment: It originates in boxing, from when lighter classes could voluntarily challenge heavier opponents for greater reward.  I've seen it used to describe anyone taking on a greater challenge in exchange for greater risk.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain it just means a mug with a "punch above your weight" slogan on it

You're also correct with the meaning of that in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

To understand why that peculiar phrase no longer appears in Urban Dictionary in 2023,  I visited [Internet Archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG1dy.png),  and discovered that Urban Dictionary used to advertise merchandise directly below the definitions.

Note that these images belong to a single snapshot of the website, which was taken in **May 11, 2021**

[image]

> Get the **Punch above your weight** neck gaiter and mug

and

[image]

> Get a **punch above your weight** mug for your daughter Rihanna

The company even encouraged aficionados of Urban Dictionary to buy mugs for the family dog, whose name could have been Callisto.

> [image]
> Get a **punch above your weight** mug for your dog Callisto